# Implement hmset in python with dictionary of list and nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redis

I was trying to implement below redis code into python django application

```
hmset test_template:TEMPLATE_ID test_tags "[{\"key\":\"test_manual_entry_1\",\"value\":\"Some_value_1\"},{\"key\":\"test_manual_entry_2\",\"value\":\"Some_value_2\"}]"
```

I have tried `hset` and `hmset` functions but both are giving the error. Below is sample of my code looks like this

```
class RedisUtil:

    def hset(self, key_name, data):
        key_name = "test_template:TEMPLATE_ID"
        list_data = [{"key": "test_manual_entry_1", "value": "Some_value1"}, {"key": "test_manual_entry_2", "value": "Some_value2"}]
        data = {"test_tags": [json.dumps(d) for d in list_data]}  # output list: ['{"key": "test_manual_entry_1", "value": "Some_value1"}', '{"key": "test_manual_entry_2", "value": "Some_value2"}']
```

I have tried below methods to save but all methods are giving me error

```
# Method 1
self.redis_client.hset(key_name, data)  # Exception: redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.

#Method 2
self.redis_client.hset(key_name, "test_tag", data["test_tags"])  # Exception: redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'list'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.
```

Also, I would like add there that there may be case where my list will be empty, this could be an edge case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Python Redis hset doc: https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html?highlight=hset#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.hset

The function signature is `hset(name, key=None, value=None, mapping=None, items=None)`.

For method 1, You passed `data` as key. Besides, I presume data is a dict, which is differ from string.

For method 2, you use `data["test_tags"]` as value, But still, `data["test_tags"]` isn't a string but a list.

If you want to implement `hmset`, may you should use [this one](https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html?highlight=hset#redis.commands.cluster.RedisClusterCommands.hmset) instead(but already deprecated, not recommended)?

Comment: according to this, I have passed the type correct my key_name is str and data is dict. but getting the same error

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava you mean you want to use `data` as `mapping` parameter? Then you need to explicitly give `None` to other parameters. Maybe `hset(key_name, None, None, data)`.

Comment: It is solved by converting data into string. I have used ```str(data)```